# How can I show items based on Session Variable php

Tags: php, variables, session

Trying to display this data in the diary post page solely based on the Session variable.

The Session variable is already declared in the php/ functions file.

The data foreign key is already linked between the User ID in the accounts table and the diary post table in PHP my admin

I just need an Inner join query of some description to only show the data based on Session.

Functions declared at the top of diary page

```html
<?php
include("php/functions.php");
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
?>
```

The functions file

```html
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
 session_start();
        
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['myEmail'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: login.php");
}

 if (!isset($_SESSION['myEmail'])) {
  echo"  <a href='login.php'";
   }
   else {
             $myFName = $_SESSION['userFirstName'];
          }
```

Where I need to display the posts based on Session variable

```html
          <?php
// index.php
include 'mysql.php';
          


echo '<h1>My Positive Experience Diary</h1>';
echo "<em>Post 10 Positive Recent Experiences</em><hr/>";

$result = mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');

if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No posts yet.';
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>';
        $body = substr($row['body'], 0, 300);
        echo nl2br($body).'...<br/>';
        echo '<a href="post_view.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read More</a> | ';   
        echo '<hr/>';
    }
}

echo <<<HTML
<a href="post_add.php">+ New Post</a>
HTML;

?>
```

The mysql.php where the diarypost page is getting its data.

```html
<?php
// mysql.php
function mysql_safe_string($value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if(empty($value))           return 'NULL';
    elseif(is_numeric($value))  return $value;
    else                        return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
}
function mysql_safe_query($query) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    return mysql_query(vsprintf($query,$args));
}
function redirect($uri)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {    
        header('Location: '.$uri);
        exit;
        }
    else
        {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$uri.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$uri.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
    }
}
@mysql_connect('localhost','########','########');
@mysql_select_db('########');
```

What it looks like posting all the data from the database not based on User ID

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ma5.png)

Comment: USe the MySQL `where` clause `mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userID = '. $_SESSION["userID"] .' ORDER BY date DESC');`

Comment: While doing SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC, you are not filtering on any user id, you ask for every post recorded in the posts table. Where do you want to filter on the session variable?

Comment: Thank you so much - how would I add an ID to the User's posts                                    <?php
// post_add.php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include 'mysql.php';
    if(mysql_safe_query('INSERT INTO posts (title,body,date,) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'], time()))
        echo 'Entry posted. <a href="post_view.php?id='.mysql_insert_id().'">View</a>';
    else
        echo mysql_error();
}
?>